# How to get the name or instance of the child component in patent component in angular?

Tags: angular, angular-inheritance

Suppose I have three components: P1, C1, and C2.

When constructor or Child C1 get called with super we call the constructor of parent P1 component similarly for C2 child, now I want to know from which child (C1/C2) the parent constructor get called.

How to get the name or instance of the child component in patent component in angular?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Parent` class can be inherited by components `C1` and `C2` by using the extends keyword.

When this is done the properties and methods are inherited by the child.

When two classes/components inherit a single class `P1` Then that means there are two separate scopes of `P1` inherited by the children, each component has its own set of `properties/methods` from the parent and **changes are both completely isolated from each other**.

During inheritance, its mandatory to call the `super()` inside the constructor of the children. This is required to call the constructor of the parent. In angular, you can use this super, to pass the `dependency injection` properties like `router`, `activatedRoute` to the parent, so that the parent methods have access to them.

This is a great method for `core reusability/sharing` between multiple components!

#### Method 1

Parent

```
export class A {
   fromWhichChild: string  = '';
}
```

Child B

```
export class B extends A{
   fromWhichChild: string  = '';

   constructor() {
       this.fromWhichChild = 'B';
       super();
   }
}
```

Child C

```
export class C extends A{
   fromWhichChild: string  = '';

   constructor() {
       this.fromWhichChild = 'C';
       super();
   }
}
```

---

#### Method 2

Parent

```
export class A {
   fromWhichChild: string  = '';

   constructor(fromWhichChild: string) {
       this.fromWhichChild = fromWhichChild;
   }
}
```

Children can do

```
export class C extends A{

   constructor() {
       super('C');
   }
}
```